# How can I give a different address to a sender for each transaction in an easy way?

Tags: integrated-address

Basically the subject. I've been reading on stackoverflow and the FAQ and can't find the answer.

What I want is give them different addresses each they send XMR to me. If the only choice is creating a new wallet each time, is there a way to automate the process? I couldn't find in the RPC docs a way to do this. https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/daemon-rpc

Comment: Your confidential transactions tag did not seem relevant. Are you looking for a way to automate the creation new integrated addresses (address + payment ID) for each customer?

Comment: I don't understand the use case here... Does the sender not know that they are sending to the same person each time? Because if they do know that, there's not really any reason to give them a different address. Monero uses stealth addresses, which means no one beside you and the sender will know that they are sending to you multiple times. It does make sense to generate a new payment ID each time, however, which can be done through any random number generation scheme.

Answer (score 6):

Creating a new wallet is the only way, yes (assuming you want to give different addresses for the purposes of preventing correlation). An integrated address will allow trivial correlation, as its intent is different.

There is no RPC to create a new wallet. New wallets have to be created with a simplewallet command line (ie, simplewallet --generate-new-wallet).

Newer versions of Monero (ie, 0.10.0) are very much faster in creating new wallets, however, since they know they do not have to scan the blockchain up to the point of creation.

When the GUI is out, it will include a way to create a new wallet, though I do not know how easy/quick the process will be.

Answer (score 4):

The Pull request [#1345](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1345) is a proposition for a mechanism like that.

> This is an implementation of the one-time receiving address idea discussed earlier in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/58oizb/).